# Share definition of CoroutineExecutorExtension

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, junit5

I have created two classes:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
open class InstantExecutorExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance()
            .setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
                override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()

                override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()

                override fun isMainThread(): Boolean = true
            })
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }
}
```

and

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutineExecutorExtension : InstantExecutorExtension() {

    private val testCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        super.beforeEach(context)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        super.afterEach(context)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testCoroutineDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}
```

I'm using these classes to write unit tests for method that use coroutines and livedata.
The problem I have is that I don't know how to share these classes in different modules.
If I define them in the `test` folder then I can build the classes but they are not visible in other modules.
If I define in the `main` folder there are compile time errors.
What can I do to avoid having to define these classes in all the modules?

**UPDATE**
To follow @Sam suggestion I have created a module that contains the two classes in the folder:

```
.\unittest\src\testFixtures\java\com\name\terminal\unittest
```

The `build.gradle` file of this module uses the plugins:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'java-test-fixtures'
}
```

In the module where I want to use the `CoroutineExecutorExtension` I have imported the project of the unittest module with:

```
    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":unittest")))
```

The problem is that the classes in the testFixtures folder are not visiible.

**EDIT**

This method does not work for an Android library. I can't use a java library because I need to be able to include Androidx dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Gradle, the [test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) plugin is an appropriate solution. The plugin is built in, so you can simply add `java-test-fixtures` to your `plugins` block.

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-test-fixtures`
}
```

This automatically creates a new `testFixtures` source set, alongside the existing `main` and `test` source sets that you already have. Code that you write inside `src/testFixtures/kotlin` will be visible from your tests, and will have access to everything in `main`. Anything that the test fixtures need (for example, dependencies on `kotlinx-coroutines` or your test framework) should be added as [dependencies of the test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#declaring_dependencies_of_test_fixtures).

You can also also [add dependencies on test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#consuming_test_fixtures_of_another_project) from another module. For example, if `module-b` needs to use the test fixtures from `module-a`, then in the Gradle build script for `module-b` you could add:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":module-a")))
}
```

The examples I've given are for Kotlin build scripts, but you can find the Groovy equivalents in the linked documentation.

Comment: In my case, adding plugin didn't auto create testFixtures source set. I needed to do android{ testFixtures { enable = true }} then the manually added testFixture folder become visible in android studio as testFixtures source set.